# JavaScript alternatives to handling switch cases that have properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML elements defined like this

```
<div id="Jacob" validation="required alpha-numeric"></div>
<div id="Peter" validation="required minlen:4 maxlen:20"></div>
```

And in Javascript I was parsing and handling the `validation="property1 property2 ... propertyN"` like this:

```
 // called from a foreach that uses split(' ')

 validate(type) {
     switch(type) {
        case "required":
            // ...
        break;
        case "alpha-numeric":
            // ...
        break;
     }
 }
```

I realise using a switch like this might be a bit verbose and archaic.

**What would be an elegant way to parse parameters that have their own properties/values?**

Comment: Have a look at http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/apa.html#dont_use_switch .

Comment: @Surender nice reference, but you should quote text/code from the link as links are bound to change or relocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got the impression that `switch` statements are archaic. They're not.

As far as your particular case, you can use `.split(":")` to split the individual parts apart, and then match on that:

```
function validate(type) {
    var parts = (type || "").split(":");

    switch(parts[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "required":
            // ...
        break;
        case "alpha-numeric":
            // ...
        break;
        case "minlen":
            // validate against parts[1]
        break;
    }
 }
```

If you wanted to use a lookup rather than a `switch`, you can do that, but I'd say that's just a matter of preference:

```
var validators = {
    "required": function (value) {
    },
    "alpha-numeric": function (value) {
    },
    "minlen": function (value, len) {
    }
};

function validate (value, type) {
    var parts = (type || "").split(":");

    var validator = validators[parts[0].toLowerCase()];

    if (validator) {
        var result = validator(value, parts[1]);
    }
 }
```

One potential benefit of the second approach is that new validators can be added to the `validator` object at runtime, though if you wanted to make a pluggable system, you'd probably want to go with something more robust than just a plain object that can be arbitrarily modified.

Comment: Switch statements are far from archaic, but this usage, where the potential params are arbitrarily chosen, it might make more sense in the long-run to use key-value pairs or something a little more implicit for the 1-1 relationship. This is a great, simple answer and I'll accept it once StackOverflows minimum acceptance passes! :)

Comment: @ReeceComo Sure, you could use key-value pairs. I wouldn't say either approach is better than the other, and I think most JavaScript engines include optimization for switch statements so there's no "brute forcing" going on, but if you prefer the key-value approach, I've added an example of that above.

Comment: Thank you, you've gone above and beyond.

Comment: I think it would be better to write validation params as json. Parsing them will require using parseJSON() only

Answer (score 0):

you can create json of key function pair. And pick function using your type and call it.

```
    var objOfFunction = {};
objOfFunction["required"] = requiredFunction;
objOfFunction["alpha-numeric"] = alphanFunction;
function validate(type) {
     objOfFunction[type]();
 }

 function requiredFunction(){
 alert("required");
 }

  function alphanFunction(){
  alert("in alpha");
  }
 validate("required");
 validate("alpha-numeric");
```